# Sort a list of dates by time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array objects like this:

```
[
 {
  _id: 1
  date: '2018-05-04T12:28:00-07:00' //12:28pm
 },
 {
  _id: 2
  date: '2018-04-29T08:24:00-07:00' //8:24am
 },
 {
  _id: 3
  date: '2018-05-04T10:29:00-07:00' //10:29am
 }
```

Now, I want to sort this array by "TIME" only regardless of the dates

Sorted array should look like this:

```
[
 {
  _id: 2
  date: '2018-04-29T08:24:00-07:00' //8:24am
 },
 {
  _id: 3
  date: '2018-05-04T10:29:00-07:00' //10:29am
 },
 {
  _id: 1
  date: '2018-05-04T12:28:00-07:00' //12:28pm
 }
]
```

How can I write this code in Javascript?

I tried:

```
sorted.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a.start_ts).getUTCHours() - new Date(b.start_ts).getUTCHours()
})
```

but seems to throw me an error, "cannot The sort method cannot be invoked on an Immutable data structure."

Comment: Are the `date` properties strings or Date objects? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Syntax looks to be invalid.

Comment: the date should be in string format and commas separating object attributes is also missing.

Comment: also..., no comments //

Comment: They are strings sorry

Comment: The comments // are added on the post for reference . In the real array of objects, doesn't have the comments //

Comment: There objects being sorted don't have `a.start_ts` or `b.start_ts` properties, so unlikely to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to mess with Dates, simply extract the hours/minutes/seconds of each string and sort accordingly:

```js
const arr = [{
    _id: 1,
    date: '2018-05-04T12:28:00-07:00' //12:28pm
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    date: '2018-04-29T08:24:00-07:00' //8:24am
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    date: '2018-05-04T10:29:00-07:00' //10:29am
  }
];
const hmsVal = str => {
  const [,h, m, s] = str.match(/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/);
  return Number(h) * 3600 + Number(m) * 60 + Number(s);
};
arr.sort((a, b) => hmsVal(a.date) - hmsVal(b.date));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This assumes the time zones are the same on all objects.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the OP's code fails, or how it fixes it. It just provides completely new code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't work as the objects being sorted don't have a *start_ts* property. It also helps if you post valid javascript.

Given the format of the time component, the objects can be sorted as strings using the *date* property and *localeCompare*:

```js
var data = [
   {_id: 1, date: '2018-05-04T12:28:00-07:00'},
   {_id: 2, date: '2018-04-29T08:24:00-07:00'},
   {_id: 3, date: '2018-05-04T10:29:00-07:00'}
];

data.sort((a, b) => a.date.substr(11,8).localeCompare(b.date.substr(11,8)));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering **sort this array by "TIME" only regardless of the dates**,

```js
const input = [{
    _id: 1,
    date: "2018-05-04T12:28:00-07:00"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    date: "2018-04-29T08:24:00-07:00"
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    date: "2018-05-04T10:29:00-07:00"
  }
];
input.sort((a,b) => {
  return getDate(a) - getDate(b)
});

function getDate(i) {
  let temp = new Date(i.date);
  let currentDate = new Date();
  temp.setUTCFullYear(currentDate.getUTCFullYear(),
    currentDate.getUTCMonth(),
    currentDate.getUTCDate());
  return temp;
}
console.log(input);
```

[setUTCFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCFullYear).

Comment: You should only create one additional Date, not 5. After initialising *temp*, set it to a fixed date and return the time value in one statement: `return temp.setUTCFullYear(1970,0,1)`. Also, `new Date(temp)` does nothing useful, it just creates a copy of *temp*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG. Thanks. Have updated my answer as you suggested.